# SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio) for professionals

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This is a very elementary doubt as I am trying to build some fundamental knowledge.

I downloaded SSMS in my local machine (laptop). I agree that we can save data/entries in my local machine, but then suppose if I make a web app where users can upload videos/image files, then certainly I cannot or don't want to use my local machine to save their files.

My doubt is,  SSMS , i.e., the management studio software which is installed in my local machine , is it possible to use it for online data handling of other users around the world?

Surely, the software must not be only for newbies learning to get a hang of database stuffs in an offline mode, but it must be also used by professionals handling real world data? Do professionals really use the software for their projects?

Comment: *"My doubt is, SSMS , i.e., the management studio software which is installed in my local machine , is it possible to use it for online data handling of other users around the world?"* Huh? SSMS is an IDE, and it's certainly not designed for newbies as you suggest. Professionals use a range of tools when working with SQL Server, including SSMS. Some of those will likely be 3rd party applications or extensions, that have licence fees, others will be MS products, such as Visual Studio and Azure Data Studio. What are you *actually* asking here? What is your programming question?

Comment: "is it possible to use it for online data handling of other users around the world" - No, for that you write a Web (or Desktop or Mobile) application with a server backend which will connect with your database. SSMS has no role here except as a management tool for the Database administrators or Application developers.

Comment: @PeterB "except as a management tools for database administrators or application developers" u mean offline data?

Comment: @peaceHoper What do you mean by offline data ?

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh suppose I have a web app which can accept images/videos from users, then can I handle the data of those users of internet using ssms?

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh offline data in the sense, like when we use for practice in local machines..

Comment: *"then can I handle the data of those users of internet using ssms?"* That's application logic, it has nothing to do with the IDE. If you want an interface to interact with your data, you should be building an application to do that.

Answer (score 2):

To a degree, the answer is in the name, SQL Server "MANAGEMENT" Studio. SSMS is a tool for managing SQL Server instances. Whether those are running locally on the machine that has SSMS installed, remotely on some server within your environment, or up on the cloud hosted in Azure, AWS or Google. You can connect to any Microsoft SQL Server instance through SSMS and then you can manipulate the server and the databases within the server. It is a sophisticated tool with a great deal of depth.

It is absolutely not intended to be a front-end for individual users to manipulate the data within a database. Does it have this capacity? Yes, in an extremely limited fashion. It's a very secondary aspect of the tool and not it's primary purpose. See above.

For the kind of data manipulation you're describing, the standard response is to A) Purchase a software designed to manage the data you want, B) Build a tool that does what you need. It's really that simple. For example, you talk about want to manage videos. For option A, you could look to a service such as Vimeo to handle your videos. Or, if what you want is unique, you're going to have to build a new piece of software, option B.

Regardless, SSMS is not the end-user solution. It's absolutely meant as a development and management tool. That's why it's called Management Studio.